# Accepted term for method that simply calls another method

Tags: terminology, methods

Is there a generally accepted term for a method that does nothing more than calling another method (and returning its result)?

Comment: Think there may be a name in some circumstances depending on the context-- facade, wrapper, invoker, empty constructor, etc. Do you have any specifics?

Comment: Somewhat related post: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141251/functions-that-only-call-other-functions-is-this-a-good-practice

Comment: @JohnWu: In automated testing, in order to be able to test a protected method, one could inherit from the class under test and provide a public function (X) that calls the method you want to test. When doing this, I wanted to make clear in the name of method X that it's just that: a method that calls another method.

Comment: The method would be called "a public member that *hides* a protected member of the same name." The class containing such a method would be called a [shim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596843/using-shims-to-test-private-method).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By itself, such a function would be a [wrapper function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function).  These are normally used to hide an ugly API or obsolete function names.

A more sophisticated object-oriented wrapper may be designed as a facade or adaptor.

Comment: It can do a bit more than just that. See also, [Composition over Inheritance](https://www.google.com/search?q=Composition+over+Inheritance&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1), [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), and good old [Delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation). This is how many people accomplish [Indirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection).